# Suitable English word to express tongue motion

Tags: word-usage, gestures

I am actually a little bit confused to how to say the following tongue motion?

[image: sometimes zayn does this thing with his tongue when he smiles]
[image: sometimes zayn does this thing with his tongue when he smiles]

I am actually talking about **tongue out with somewhat between the teeth**.

Is **sticking tongue out** a suitable word for it (as I don't think so) or something else?

Comment: Does : p count?

Comment: sorry? I didn't get it...

Comment: :P is an emoji.  Look at it sideways and you'll see a face sticking it's tongue out at you.  Though it's not really a word per say it gets a lot of online use.

Comment: LOL! yeah it fits the needs but I can't say to my friend that "Kids look cute when they :P"

Comment: A cute question title, but tongues have no emotions. (0: I would formulate it as "tongue position".

Comment: Collectively, all types of "body language" involving the tongue are called ["tongue shows"](http://dor.academy/en/the-non-verbal-language-of-the-tongue/). Your examples fall under *Biting the tongue typically indicates that the biter wants to say something but somehow feels unable or unwilling to say what they want, perhaps for fear of offending or breaking social rules.* But I doubt there's a term for that specific "show" or the likely significance.

Answer (score 0):

"Lamino-dental" or "fronting" are the names commonly used when describing mouth positions with respect to pronunciation. "Tongue-thrusting" is the term used when the motion accompanies swallowing. Otherwise I'm not sure that there's an emotive descriptor for that position.